# C: "this" vs "<instance name>"

Tags: object-oriented, c, this

I'm using C in a minimal, efficient OOP style to build a game engine. A problem I've begun to face as the engine code settles is my (erstwhile) choice to use `this`. For example, I have:

```
void Engine_initialise(Engine * this);

void Window_terminate(Window * this);
```

`Window * this` contains a reference to the singleton `Engine`. Now, let's say I reference this `Engine` member from both `Engine_initialise(..)` and `Window_terminate(..);`. In the former it will be `this->member`, yet in the latter it will be (`window->`)`engine->member`.

This inconsistency annoys me; if it *is* the same, it should *look* the same. And as I work purely in a text editor without IDE, I want a single find-replace across all files, instead of multiple find-replaces.

Let's consider another example, where there isn't only one argument of the given type.

```
Blob_compare(Blob * this, Blob * that);
```

vs.

```
Blob_compare(Blob * blob, Blob * blobOther); //or blob1 and blob2, or whatever
```

...in spite of my preference for losing `this`, the former looks better as it is descriptive and concise.

**Question**: Are there any particularly strong arguments for continuing to use `this` as the name of current object instance in my various functions? I'm thinking of replacing all `this` with `engine` (or similar). I would like to settle on a coding standard in this regard, for all C code.

I am asking about the usefulness of `this` as the *primary* function argument; the names of other parameters of similar type are not of major importance here in spite of my second example. To me it seems sensible, if the function is prefixed with `Blob_`, to assume that `blob` refers to the current instance. And no, I really don't care one iota about renaming types - these are well fixed.

Comment: Why do you need the parameter to always be called the same thing or even have some kind of "standard". As a counterexample, look at the docs for FILE-based functions in the standard library. The tendency is to name the FILE parameters *stream*. I.e. you don't have to write `FILE *file` in the prototype to make it clear how to use your functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are supposed to be singletons, and you really want to do things in your (conceptual) style, you might want to use [Context object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ContextObjectsAreEvil).

*(First and foremost: apologies. C is not my native language; C++ is.)*

Basically,

```
struct Context
{
    Engine * engine;
    Window * window;
    // any other things that are considered singletons 
    // according to your conceptual style
};

void Engine_initialize(Context * context);
void Window_terminate(Context * context);
```

---

For reference, take a look at `jpeglib` and `libtiff` on their use of some root level objects which contain pointers to all other relevant stuff needed by the code.

---

As a sidenote, using `this` as the identifier name in C code (and header files) will create griefs for people who try to integrate your C code into C++ projects. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500496/is-it-wise-to-use-the-this-keyword-in-c) for opinions on this.

Comment: Another reason against using `this` in C code pretty much topples it for me. Thanks rwong. I will wait a while for other answers but this is looking likely.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing about C++ integration, what a nightmare since "this" is a keyword.

Comment: Why would you want to give `Engine_initialize()` understanding of a structure beyond `Engine`?  If a `Context` has an `Engine`, there should be a `Context_initialize()` that calls `Engine_initialize()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to avoid using `this` as a formal name in C, because `this` is a C++ keyword. You could use e.g. `self` (or `me` or `recv`, or `ipse` -it is *self* in Latin) instead of `this`

If you code your C code without using C++ keywords, you are much more likely to be able to use your code with a C++ compiler.

In particular, quite often a C header file `foo.h` (with some `static inline` functions) which does not use any C++ keyword is very likely to be usable from a C++ program (perhaps by surrounding the `#include "foo.h"` directive with `extern "C" {`  & `};`, because C++ has been (originally) designed to be upward compatible with C (this is slightly less true with C++11 and C11).

Comment: `self` is already taken by Objective-C, which, like C++, expands on C. So `self` has the same problem as `this`. For that reason, `me` looks like the smartest choice to me.